# Return Output From Kix Script C#

Tags: c#, kix

I have a very simple kix script file (myKix.kix)

```
? "Hello World"
```

When running the following command in the cmd The kix script runs fine and outputs Hello World to the cmd (IS THIS THE OUTPUT FOR process.StandardOutput?)

```
directoryWhereKix32Is > kix32.exe myKix
```

I wrote this code to consume the output in .Net but the output is returning no error but an empty string. What am I missing?

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryWhereKix32Is;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"directoryWhereKix32Is\KIX32.EXE";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "myKix";
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Eh, *first* `process.WaitForExit();` and only *then* `string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`? Give executable a chance to output anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *swap* two lines:

```
 string output;

 // wrap IDisposable into using
 using (var process = new Process()) {
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryWhereKix32Is;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"directoryWhereKix32Is\KIX32.EXE";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "myKix";

        process.Start();

        // First wait for exit; give KIX32.EXE a chance to execute the script
        process.WaitForExit();
        // Only then (when execution compteted) read into output    
        output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  }
```